# Debugging two different programs from two different Visual Studios

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2003

I have two Windows console programs, one was developed in C++ VS2003 and the other one in C# VS2010. The C++ program calls the C# program.

I'd like to debug both using two Visual Studios without having to stop in the middle of 1st program, then copy the parameters of 2nd program, and then use them to run the 2nd program separately. Is it possible to link the two to make the debugging process flow seamlessly?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not really.  You could call Debugger.Launch() in the Main() method of your C# program.

Comment: "The C++ program calls the C# program." How is this done? Process invoke? or consuming APIs like dll?

Comment: Not to point out the potentially obvious, but you *can* debug both processes from the *same* Visual Studio concurrently if you desire.

Comment: #Hans: Thanks for the pointer. I'll try it. #Ankush: The C# program is executed as a separate process from C++ program. #WhozCraig: I didn't know that. Do you have any link to the information regarding how to set it up? Thanks.